# Scientific notation values in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that gets populated with excel.The datatable does not have fixed columns as it depends on the excel provided by the client.
While reading excel to datatable, the decimal values are getting converted to scientific notation values.
I do not want to save these values in database as scientific notation but as decimals.
I know I can convert a scientific notion value to decimal but how to find out the column of datatable that contains scientific values as columns of datatable depends on the excel provided.

Comment: *"While reading excel to datatable, the decimal values are getting converted to scientific notation values"* -- mistakes were made, eh? What exactly is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

When you read in the data from excel, you can try to convert number from each column by using

```
bool result = Decimal.TryParse(number_in_string)
```

A succesful returned result means the scientific notation is parsed. You can use this to see which column contains the scientific notation.

Comment: Actually I am using  ExceldataReader as below                                                                                       FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

Comment: You should still be able to access each row and column in the result DataSet